# Is it possible to calculate a distribution while doing a group by in R

Tags: r, group-by, distribution

I know when doing a `group_by` I can `summarise` and calculate frequency, sum, mean, median, std etc. I was wondering if while summarizing I can calculate a probability distribution. E.g.

```
dat%>%group_by(A, B)%>%summarise(C_dist = density(C))
```

I tried doing it in r. But I get following error.

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: need at least 2 points to select a bandwidth automatically.
```

I do not have any missing values in the columns.

Comment: Do any of your groups have only a single entry? Try summarise(freq = n())

Comment: Yes. Some of them have single entry. I can ignore them. But then again the density is not a single value. How can I store it in the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather use `tapply()`

The `tryCatch` bit makes sure that when a group only has one member, NA is returned rather than having the whole thing stop.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 20
dtf <- data.frame(d=runif(n), 
                 g1=sample(1:3, n, replace=TRUE), 
                 g2=sample(c("A", "B"), n, replace=TRUE))

agg <- with(dtf, 
         tapply(d, list(g1, g2), 
         FUN=function(x) {
             tryCatch(density(x), error=function(e) NA)
         }))

str(agg)
agg[["2", "A"]]
# Call:
#    density.default(x = x)

# Data: x (3 obs.); Bandwidth 'bw' = 0.1733

#        x                 y           
#  Min.   :-0.2543   Min.   :0.008613  
#  1st Qu.: 0.1663   1st Qu.:0.156751  
#  Median : 0.5869   Median :0.699978  
#  Mean   : 0.5869   Mean   :0.593340  
#  3rd Qu.: 1.0074   3rd Qu.:0.902087  
#  Max.   : 1.4280   Max.   :1.199607
```

Comment: Thank you. this will work. How will it scale on a large dataset? Do you think instead of creating a matrix of the agg we should return it as (g1,g2,density)? If I want to generalize it for more than one variable e.g. d1,d2 ... can I do it in one call?

Comment: I don't know, I only came up with it this second. You can try increasing `n` and the number of groups gradually and see what happens.

Comment: I believe this approach only works for one variable at a time. One option would be to put it inside a loop and loop over the variables. Then you'd end up with a list of lists of lists, might be a bit unwieldy.

Comment: Perfect... Thank you